# How to byteswap 32bit integers inside a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a large string more than 256 bits and and I need to byte swap it by 32 bits. But the string is in a hexadecimal base. When I looked at numpy and array modules I couldnt find the right syntax as to  how to do the coversion. Could someone please help me?

An example:(thought the data is much longer.I can use pack but then I would have to convert the little endian to decimal and then to big endian first which seems like a waste):

```
Input:12345678abcdeafa
Output:78563412faeacdab
```

Comment: With pack, probably, but you're going to have to be less vague than that.

Comment: Each hex digit is 4 bits, I guess you can slice the string in half-word-size chunks and swap odd/even chunks.

Comment: That doesn't look like an endian swap, unless you have 4-bit bytes.

Comment: Yep. Its just a 32 bit byte swap. I will rename the question.

Comment: ...but what you have there doesn't swap bytes, unless you have 4-bit bytes.  Assuming 8-bit bytes, swapping `12345678` gives `78563412`, not `87654321`.

Comment: Okay. What happens is I take the first 32 bits(each digit is 4 bits since its in hex) and then I convert each 8 bit part from the end of the 8 bit into big endian. I dont know what the right technical term is  for it though. This is simply the way it is documented

Comment: So do you want `78563412` or `87654321` as the output, then? "convert each 8 bit part from the end of the 8 bit into big endian" doesn't make sense, I think.

Comment: 87654321 is what I need. I dont know what its called though. I guess I will just use an array and do it manually. I just wanted to know if there was some automated way or function for this. But looks like there isnt

Comment: Is the Input/Output a str of hex digits or a hexadecimal literal or something else??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they really are strings, just do string operations on them?

```
>>> input = "12345678abcdeafa"
>>> input[7::-1]+input[:7:-1]
'87654321afaedcba'
```

Comment: Why was this accepted? It doesn't match the OP's example output.

Comment: @MarkTolonen This answer matches what OP asked. The example output in the question has been changed by icktoofay. (What OP *actually needs* may still be 78563412faeacdab)

Comment: @Janne, OP should change it back, although I think you're right about what OP probably needs.  Not usual to need 32-bit nybble-swapped data.

Comment: What puzzles me is that why on earth did @icktoofay change the question AFTER the OP has confirmed his output to be what it was...

Comment: @Kimvais: icktoofay has 40k+ reputation, user1667307 don't have a clue. My bet is on icktoofay.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string to bytes, unpack big-endian 32-bit and pack little-endian 32-bit (or vice versa) and convert back to a string:

```
#!python3
import binascii
import struct

Input = b'12345678abcdeafa'
Output = b'78563412faeacdab'

def convert(s):
    s = binascii.unhexlify(s)
    a,b = struct.unpack('>LL',s)
    s = struct.pack('<LL',a,b)
    return binascii.hexlify(s)

print(convert(Input),Output)
```

Output:

```
b'78563412faeacdab' b'78563412faeacdab'
```

Generalized for any string with length multiple of 4:

```
import binascii
import struct

Input = b'12345678abcdeafa'
Output = b'78563412faeacdab'

def convert(s):
    if len(s) % 4 != 0:
        raise ValueError('string length not multiple of 4')
    s = binascii.unhexlify(s)
    f = '{}L'.format(len(s)//4)
    dw = struct.unpack('>'+f,s)
    s = struct.pack('<'+f,*dw)
    return binascii.hexlify(s)

print(convert(Input),Output)
```

Comment: I see that someone besides the OP changed the question, but I'll leave the answer anyway.

Comment: Most likely the original `Output` was wrong and this answer gives the right one.

Answer (score 2):

My take:

1. slice the string in N digit chunks
2. reverse each chunk
3. concatenate everything

Example:

```
>>> source = '12345678abcdeafa87654321afaedcba'
>>> # small helper to slice the input in 8 digit chunks
>>> chunks = lambda iterable, sz: [iterable[i:i+sz] 
                                   for i in range(0, len(iterable), sz)]
>>> swap = lambda source, sz: ''.join([chunk[::-1] 
                                       for chunk in chunks(source, sz)])
```

Output asked in the original question:

```
>>> swap(source, 8)
'87654321afaedcba12345678abcdeafa'
```

It is easy to adapt in order to match the required output after icktoofay edit:

```
>>> swap(swap(source, 8), 2)
'78563412faeacdab21436587badcaeaf'
```

A proper implementation probably should check if `len(source) % 8 == 0`.